# Why is "Override GPU Dispatch Num Threads Y" disabled here?

Tags: unreal-engine5

I have a Generic Simulation Stage setup with a grid as the data-source. I want to override the GPU Dispatch Num Threads in the Y-axis, but it is disabled for some reason. Any idea as to why?

I have tried to look for any potential settings that needs to be checked, but haven't found anything. I am expecting the "Override GPU Dispatch Thread Num Y" field to be enabled and editable.

[Simulation stage setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIr7Q.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try changing "Iteration Source" to "Direct Set"